# Rename table header inside do.call rbind functions in R

Tags: r

I am trying to rename the column header in table function called in rbind and do.call.
 How I can rename the output header name?
the function which I am using splits the sequence and counts the number of A, T, G and C and binds to a data frame (dat).
Target Sequence

```
CAGGATCAGGTAGACAGAG
TCTAAAGAAGAGACTGAAA
```

Code:

```
cbind(dat, do.call(rbind, lapply(dat$TargetSeq,  function(x){table(strsplit(as.character(x),""))})))
```

Desired Output:

```
       Tar_A Tar_C Tar_G Tar_T
 [1,]  9 2 4 4
 [2,]  6 5 4 4
```

I will be grateful for this help.
Regards

Comment: Why do you need to do everything in one-line ? just do `tmp <- do.call(rbind, lapply(dat$TargetSeq,  function(x){table(strsplit(as.character(x),""))}))` then `colnames(tmp) <- paste0('Tar_',colnames(tmp))` and finally `cbind(dat, tmp)`

Comment: Can you share how your data is structured? Please edit your question to include the result of `dput(dat)`